# Dot product in spherical coordinates

Tags: vectors, curvilinear-coordinates

What can be the formula for dot product in spherical coordinates? that is
$$\overrightarrow{A}(r, \theta , \phi). \overrightarrow{B}(r, \theta , \phi)=?$$
$$or,(A_r \hat{r} + A_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + A_{\phi} \hat{\phi}).(B_r \hat{r} + B_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + B_{\phi} \hat{\phi})=?$$

My Approach:
As $\overrightarrow{a}.(\overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{c})=\overrightarrow{a}.\overrightarrow{b} + \overrightarrow{a}.\overrightarrow{c}$
$$\therefore (A_r \hat{r} + A_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + A_{\phi} \hat{\phi}).(B_r \hat{r} + B_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + B_{\phi} \hat{\phi})= A_r \hat{r}.(B_r \hat{r} + B_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + B_{\phi} \hat{\phi})+A_{\theta} \hat{\theta}.(B_r \hat{r} + B_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + B_{\phi} \hat{\phi})+A_{\phi} \hat{\phi}.(B_r \hat{r} + B_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + B_{\phi} \hat{\phi})$$
$$=A_r B_r + A_{\theta}B_{\theta} + A_{\phi}B_{\phi} \dots \dots (1)$$
$$\text{as  }  \hat{r}.\hat{r}=1; \hat{r}.\hat{\theta}=0;\hat{r}.\hat{\phi}=0 \space \& \space \hat{\theta}.\hat{\phi}=0 \text{ and so on...}$$
but i am not sure whether I am correct or wrong
so please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The basis $\{\hat{e}_i\}_i= \{\hat{r},\hat{\theta},\hat{\phi} \}$ is orthonormal, so it follows

$$
\hat{e}_i\cdot \hat{e}_j = \delta_{ij}
$$

Comment: do you mean $\{\hat{r},\hat{\theta},\hat{\phi} \}$ are **fixed** (same for A and for B) ??

Comment: @GCab How is that implied by what I wrote?

Comment: I mean, what is $(1,0,0)\cdot(1,\pi/2,0)$ ?

Comment: @GCab I'm sorry but I fail to understand what that has anything to do with the reply. Are un interested in knowing the inner product of the vectors of the spherical basis and a cartesian rectangular basis?

Comment: sorry for not putting it clear before, in fact I am wondering about the relation between the dot product you show in spherical wrt the corresponding product in cartesian coordinates

Comment: @GCab I see. The easies way is to expand any of the vectors $\hat{e}_i$ in the cartesian base $\{\epsilon_i\}_i = \{\hat{x}, \hat{y},\hat{z} \}$. For example

$$
\hat{e}_1 = \hat{r} = \sin\theta\cos\phi \hat{x} + \sin\theta\sin\phi \hat{y} + \cos\theta \hat{y}
$$

So that 

$$
\hat{x}\cdot\hat{r} = \sin\theta\cos\phi
$$

Comment: thanks, that is clear, but how does it compare with yours ?